# Lodash get single array from nested array objects

Tags: arrays, nested, lodash

sorry for the newbie question.
Using lodash, how to get an array with all nested "machineries" entries from this API response ?

```
{
  "areas": [
    {
      "name": "BAR 1",
      "machineries": [
        {
          "_id": "stand BAR 1.1"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "BAR 2",
      "machineries": [
        {
          "_id": "stand BAR 2.1"
        },
        {
          "_id": "stand BAR 2.2"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Using above data I would return 3 entries:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "stand BAR 1.1"
    },
    {
        "_id": "stand BAR 2.1"
    },
    {
        "_id": "stand BAR 2.2"
    }
]
```

Thank's

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array.prototype.flatMap()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) combined with [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment):

```js
const data = {areas: [{name: 'BAR 1',machineries: [{_id: 'stand BAR 1.1',},],},{name: 'BAR 2',machineries: [{_id: 'stand BAR 2.1',},{_id: 'stand BAR 2.2',},],},],}

const result = data.areas.flatMap(({ machineries: m }) => m.map(({ _id }) => ({ _id })))

console.log(result)
```

Comment: @ClaudioBarca good to help!